# MvvmCross 6.0 UWP dependency

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, mvvmcross

I'm trying to make dependency on UWP by this tutorial https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/uwp/universal-windows-platform-uwp?scroll=621

but on this step in Setup.cs:
 `public Setup( Frame rootFrame ) : base( rootFrame ){}`

I get an error[image]

does anybody have an idea why??

Dependency on Android works well

Comment: Which version of mvvmcross are you using in your project? I used  version  4.2.3 of mvvmcross as the tutorial used and it worked well for me.

Comment: I'm using v6.1.2. Do you think that they changed functionality and didn't said anything?

Comment: I think so, the latest version of mvvmcross is 4.2.3 when they write the tutoril. And now you use 6.1.2, there must be something updated and some functions and properties has been changed.

Comment: you were right... I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
public abstract class AWSService : MvxApplication<Setup, Core.App>
{ }
```

Setup.cs

```
public class Setup : MvxWindowsSetup<Core.App>
{
    public Setup()
    { }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterType<IYourInterface, YourNativeClass>();
        return new Core.App();
    }
}
```